# Тип DataRepeater существует в двух библиотеках

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Столкнулся с проблемой, что Тип DataRepeater существует в двух библиотеках, но по сути это одна

> Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

но находит ещё и в

> Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs

раньше работала в первом варианте, но поле переустановки всех библиотек через nuget что-то пошло не так.
Как я могу указать, что `private Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeater dataRepeater1;` 
верно?

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то попробуйте просто указать using (прим.: `using DataRepeater = Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeater;`).

Comment: вот полный текст ошибки >>Тип "DataRepeater" существует как в "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", так и в "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".